# Integration of a complex number

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

I'm trying to integrate, for example, $\int e^xe^{-inx} \,dx$.

$i$ is the imaginary unit, $n$ is a constant.

I tried to integrate normally - as I would in a Real number:

$$\int e^x e^{-inx}\,dx = \int e^{x - inx}\,dx = \int e^{x(1 - in)} = \frac{e^{x(1 - in)}}{(1-in)}.$$

In the $\mathbb Real \space numbers $ field, I would be right.

[According to wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%200%20to%20pi%20%28e%5Ex%2ae%5E%28-inx%29%29), It seems that I've wrong.

How should I integrate a complex term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should I integrate a complex term?

Exactly as you did. Wolfram's response is just a different form to write the same,

$$\frac{i}{n+i} = \frac{1}{(-i)(n+i)} = \frac{1}{1-in},$$

so with the exponential factor, you have

$$\underbrace{\frac{i e^{(1-in)x}}{n+i}}_{\text{WA}} = \underbrace{\frac{e^{x(1-in)}}{1-in}}_{\text{You}}$$

the same (modulo the integration constant explicitly mentioned by WA).

Comment: But I've got $\frac{e^{x(1-in)}}{1-in)}$ not $\frac{1}{1-in}$ ..

Comment: The factor $e^{(1-in)x}$ you both have in common, I've left that out to not block the sight onto the term you two have written differently. You: $$\frac{1}{1-in}\cdot e^{(1-in)x},$$ Wolfram: $$\frac{i}{n+i}\cdot e^{(1-in)x}.$$